# How to get back to same page of post-list - after updating a post

Tags: navigation

I'm going back and reworking categories and tags on some older posts.  So I'm going back in time, to say for example page 4 of my posts.  I know there are search filters, which might help, but let's follow through with this scenario.

I'm on page 4, and update the first post on that page.  Now, is there a fast way to get back to page 4 to update the second post on that page?  If I've changed a lot of tags or categories, I don't want to hit the browser back key five to ten times.  Any shortcut I don't see in this case?

Comment: When you say *"page 4"* do you mean in the admin or on the front end? And how many total pages do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open post to edit in new browser tab/window so that page X remains in original tab/window?

Comment: You can also change categories with Quick Edit, so there's no need to even do the tab thing, but if content updates are required to, then tabbing would be(in my mind) an acceptable approach(and would be my suggestion also)... +1